# GUIDE in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am trying to build a program in MATLAB and I am using edit boxes but I want the value that the user will enter to be used later on from another function. So should I  use the `global` variables or is there another way?

I tried to define the `global` variables outside the function but is not working.
I tried to define it inside the function and then call it from another function but it says that it is undefined. Is there a way that I can do that?

I am just using

```
function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
str2double (get (hObject,'String'));
```

Thanks!! :)

Comment: use handles-structure + guidata!! you will find several answers to that topic on SO... I'm pretty sure :)

Comment: so I will use `guidata(hObject,handles)` in the function of the edit box and then `a=guidata(hObject, handles)` in the other function that I want to call it back?

Comment: no, not exactly ;-) I'll post a short answer on this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store data within a Matlab-GUI, you can use the handles-structure like this:

```
handles.myVar=123;
%after this dont forget to save it (yes, this is a bit annoying):
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

later on, within another callback for example, you can find this data within the handles-struct:

```
handles.myVar
```

Comment: I just used your code but instead of 123 I have put `str2double (get (hObject,'String'));` and it always shows me the same number :/ why is that?