# How to create new points in existing matlab figure and execute function

Tags: matlab, events, plot, onclick, matlab-figure

This is briefly my question: If I have an existing 2D simple matlab figure, I would like to create new points by clicking (or by double-clicking) to a certain point. In addition, I would like to execute a script, or function, or even a command every time I create a new point. I *did* search both on the web and here carefully but I had no luck...

Could you help please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something I found->
you need the ButtonDown-Callback:

```
ax=axes;%you need the handle of the axes
%to give additional values to the callback-fcn use:
set(ax,'ButtonDownFcn',{@mytestcallback,mydata})
%if you dont want to give extra values:
set(ax,'ButtonDownFcn',@mytestcallback)
```

next you have to define the function mytestcallback like that:

```
function mytestcallback(h,eventdata)
point = get(h,'currentpoint');
```

now, within this function you can do whatever you want, like executing another script...

**EDIT**

what I tried:

```
function test_mouse
h=figure;
plot(1:10)
myax=findall(h,'Type','axes')
set(myax,'ButtonDownFcn',@mytestcallback)

end

function mytestcallback(h,eventdata)
point = get(h,'currentpoint')
end
```

what I get, when clicking on the axes:

suprisingly, there is a matrix, like:

```
point =

3.0219    1.2500    1.0000
3.0219    1.2500   -1.0000
```

which contains the coordinates of x,y,z with a z=[1,-1]; I guess you can ignore that, if you just have 2d-data

Now, if you want to add new values, you have to get the line in the plot, get the data and update it. I would do something like:

**1.** get the handle of the line
    myline=findall(myax,'Type','line') % be careful, this will return all lines (if you have more then one)

**2.** get the data of the line:

```
xdat=get(myline,'XData')
ydat=get(myline,'YData')
```

**3.** manipulate the data:
-> well this depends on what you want to do (insert, append...)

```
xdat=newdata...
```

**4.** update data:

```
set(myline,'XData',xdat)...
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucius, but I think this is a copy-paste from somewhere... I have seen this post before, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work... I asked here in case someone has a pretty and simple solution...

Comment: well, if this is working, I'm quite sure, that this IS the most simple solution...

Comment: Great, give me some time to embed it to my code and I'll tell you! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How can I get the new values of the (new) points I give by clicking?

Comment: you get the points within the callback-function by get(h,'currentpoint'). do you mean something else perhaps?

Comment: Oh yes,that's what I was meaning, thanks! Something else now! How could I pass a variable to the mytestcallback function? For example a matrix that I want to update using the new given points? Thanks a lot!

Comment: use the cell-syntax: set(ax,'ButtonDownFcn',{@mytestcallback,mydata})-> that makes it possible to give additional values: standard= h and eventdata; additional: everything you add seperated by ,

Comment: you're great! Thanks a lot! One last (hopefully) question! Indeed I passed successfully my data into 'mytestcallback', but I want to return the updated data back outside the function, such that each time I click to create a new point, that new point to be appended to my data. At the end, my data matrix must be N rows larger, where N is the number of the points I gave by clicks! Thanks a lot again!

Comment: that depends on: are you using GUIDE for building the GUI or not-> see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184569/guide-in-matlab/18184924#18184924 or here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for all your effort. I am not building some gui, I just have a figure where I represent some results, so when I add new point those results change, and I want to represent the 'cumulative' impact of adding new points. I hope I am clear about that, do you understand me? Is there any way of doing so  using the function you posted above? Thanks a lot!

Comment: it doesnt matter: you can use every functionality of a GUI, because a figure is a GUI!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save my soul today!