# Passing Value of Variable in other functions to another Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Here's my GUIDE.

[image]

I have two different callbacks for the changing the radio button values (for enabling and disabling the edit boxes) and the clicking of push button.

The problem is that I want to determine which radio button is checked when I press the push button. I tried passing the variable with the codes below (the first three...)

```
function pbAudio_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
x = getRBValue(rbValue);
if(strcmp(x,'rbRecord'))
    myAudio = wavrecord(get(handles.edtSeconds,'String')*11025,11025);
end
wavplay(myAudio)
```

---

```
function pnlAudio_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
slctdBtn = get(eventdata.NewValue,'tag')
getRBValue(slctdBtn);
switch slctdBtn
     case 'rbRecord'
        set(handles.edtSeconds,'enable','on');
        set(handles.edtPath,'enable','off');
    case 'rbImport'
        set(handles.edtSeconds,'enable','off');
        set(handles.edtPath,'enable','on');
end
```

---

```
function getRBValue(rbValue1)
rbValue = rbValue1;
```

Unfortunately, I am receiving the error below.

```
Undefined function or variable 'rbValue'.

Error in untitled>pbAudio_Callback (line 79)
x = getRBValue(rbValue);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
    feval(varargin{:});

Error in untitled (line 43)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pbAudio_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is, that you have to get the value of rbValue into your callback. To achieve that, you can use the handles-structure of the GUI. I assume that you are using GUIDE to create the gui.

how to do this-> [GUIDE in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184569/guide-in-matlab/18184924#18184924)

```
handles.myVar=123;
%after this dont forget to save it (yes, this is a bit annoying):
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

later on, within another callback for example, you can find this data within the handles-struct:

```
handles.myVar
```

for more information, have a look:

[guidata](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)